# Remove blank lines at end of file

Tags: regular-expression, autocmd, whitespace

How can I augment/modify my trailing whitespace logic to also remove any empty or all whitespace lines at the end of a file?

My current whitespace stripping logic in my `.vimrc` is:

```
"remove trailing whitespaces automatically                                      
autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,python,markdown,shell autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> %s/\s\+$//e
```

I've tried Googling for an answer, but only get results that strip the end of the line, not that clean up at the end of the file.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons? It allows the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following substitution remove the last empty lines:

```
%s/\_s*\%$//e
```

The `\_s` atom match any white space including new line.
The `\%$` atom match the end of the buffer.

You could do:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,python,markdown,shell autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> %s/\s\+$//e|%s/\_s*\%$//e
```

Or combine both in one substitution:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,python,markdown,shell autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> %s/\(\s*$\|\_s\%$\)//e
```

To avoid that the cursor move to the end of the files when it contains some empty line you could combine it with `mkview` and `loadview` to restore the cursor and the scrolling position after the trimming:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp,java,python,markdown,shell autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> mkview|%s/\(\s*$\|\_s\%$\)//e|loadview
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straightforward solution with VimScript

```
autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> call deletebufline('%', prevnonblank('$') + 1, '$')
```

Answer (score 1):

With some help from `:help [range]`:

```
:$;?\S?+,$delete
```

The range says from `$;?\S?+` (roughly `prevnonblank('$')`, though with no special casing for the last line containing text) to `$` (end of file), execute the deletion.

The address `$;?\S?+` says to search backwards from the end of the file for non-whitespace and address the following line.

(This doesn't work for buffers with no trailing blank lines; instead it deletes content after the last row of blanks, even if there's text after that. For that, you probably want something more programmatic like [Matt's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/44209/10604).)

Comment: @Friedrich thanks for the feedback; I belatedly realized that my "This doesn't work for buffers with no trailing blank lines" wasn't sufficient.